# Pipelining in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

How many stalls do I need to execute the following instructions properly. I am a little confused with what I did, so I am here to see experts answers.

```
lw $1,0($2);

beq $1,$2,Label;
```

Note that the check whether the branch will occur or not will be done in decoding stage. But the source register rs of beq which is $1 in this case will be updated after writeback stage of lw instruction. So do we need to forward new data from Memory in memory stage to Decoding stage of beq instruction.

Stage go like this:

[image]

IF: Instruction fetching;
ID: Instruction Decoding
Ex: Execution/ALU stage
MEM: reading data from memory
WB: storing data in destination register

This is what I have done so far.

When lw is in exec stage and beq in decoding stage, stalling condition becomes true and a bubble is created. Now lw is in Mem stage and beq is still in decoding stage due to bubble, again the stalling condition has become true and second stall has occured.and now lw is in WB (write back) and beq is in decoding stage but still the value of $1 will update at the end of WB stage which eventually means beq will still work with wrong value of $1.

Comment: "check whether the branch will occur or not" - which check do you mean. According to http://www.csc.gatech.edu/~copeland/3055-00/lab/lab-2/MIPS_pipes.JPEG branch is done in EX; and new PC is forwarded to PC register at MEM.

Comment: You need to add 1 extra stall because of delayed branch. So you will need 7 stalls.

Comment: how does it become 7 stalls?? At the most the stalls can be 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you will need a third stall to allow the register to be written back to the register file before decoding, or forward the data from the write-back stage to the decode stage. Either way this should be executed if the register to be written is equal to `rs`.

You seem to need too many stalls because the branch is detected early in the decode stage, which is good, because it saves fetching unnecessary instructions that will be flushed anyway, but you must have proper hazard detection to go with that.

Comment: ok. Thats what I think. And I had an argument with my professor and he says that I need only two stalls and no write back for above case. This is the reason I am confused

Comment: @Alfred your professor is probably assuming that the register file is asynchronous and that it will be updated before the next clock, but that's probably not the type of memory you're using or want to use.